# "flutter pub get" A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I keep getting this error on Android Studio flutter project, although `flutter doctor` command shows no issues!

```
    Cannot create link, path = 'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\_temp\dir90f89940\ios\Classes\FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m' 
(OS Error: A required privilege is not held by the client.
, errno = 1314)
pub get failed (66; , errno = 1314))
```

I tried with `pub upgrade` which seams to get dependencies correctly and start updating them, but I didn't know why `pub get` give this error.

**Update**

A workaround seems to be running Android Studio as administrator!

Comment: are you sure you are the admin and you and the program have sufficient rights to change C: files

Comment: @Monik Of course, the current user is administrator, but we do not know who is the `client` here the error means!

Comment: Do check this link:https://www.advscheduler.com/user-account-options-and-privileges

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I have switched ON developer mode in Windows settings (Settings -> Update & security -> For developers) . It worked for me.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: This should be required reading for all developers working in a Windows 10 environment. 

Comment: That's brilliant, it worked as soon as I turned on Developer mode.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I'm using vscode I just opened it as administrator and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just run your PowerShell in administrator mode

the

> cd to your project and run

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Android Studio:

open Android Studio with "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this solution because when you have accounts managed by your company this is a common problem.
Just go to your quick acces in Start then:

- Right Click > More > Open File Location
  When the Explorer Opens Right Click again on the AS Icon (quick access), then:
- Properties > Advanced ... > Run as Administrator
  So you can run always by default as Administrator.

Regards.-

Answer (score 0):

Just run your IDE whether VS Code or Android Studio as Administrator . It solves the issue

Comment: Programs don't need admin access to access `%LocalAppData%`, this shouldn't be necessary. I made sure the folder is accessible in user mode but am still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Other temporary solution is that making **pub cache** and then trying **flutter pub get**.

https://spikez.tistory.com/439

---

Solution :

1.  **flutter pub get**

==> error will be occurred.

[your flutter sdk folder]\flutter.pub-cache_temp\ **dir7d36fb45**\macos\Classes\FlutterBluePlugin.h' (OS Error: 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다. , errno = 2)

2. copy **dir7d36fb45**  to [your flutter sdk folder]\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org
3. change name **dir7d36fb45** to **flutter_blue-0.8.0**
4. cd **flutter_blue-0.8.0** (created by you)
5. create **pubspec.yaml** in flutter_blue-0.8.0 folder
6. fill below content in **pubspec.yaml**
7. now you have done preparing flutter_blue cache  :)
8. lets do, flutter pub get
   maybe it will be work.
   I know it is a temporary solution. but I believe it will help you understand how to work pub get..
    
   If you need new pubspec.yaml ,
   you can find out in here  : https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/pubspec.yaml