# How can i solve this problem (OS Error: A required privilege is not held by the client. errno = 1314)

Tags: flutter

When I am trying to import pub get to show me this error in my debug & output -

```
Cannot create link, path = 'C:\Users\ramja\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\_temp\dir61e8dc93\ios\Classes\FLTPackageInfoPlugin.m' (OS Error: A required privilege is not held by the client.       
, errno = 1314)
Running "flutter pub get" in source_code...
pub get failed (66; , errno = 1314))
```

How can I solve this problem for anyone here?

My Flutter doctor said - No issue.

Comment: try to delete pub cache directory so it again fetch all packages

Answer (score 3):

To solve this simply run vscode as Administrator

Answer (score 3):

This question has an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69735375/14952004.

> I have switched ON developer mode in Windows settings (Settings -> Update & security -> For developers) . It worked for me.

You can try to activate developer mode on Windows settings.